# sql procedure gives error "'TBL' is not a recognized built-in function nam"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

i have created the below store procedure :

```
USE [Att]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
 @DEPTNAME varchar(MAX) = '*'
AS
DECLARE @strSql varchar(max)

Set @strSql = 'SELECT DISTINCT  USERINFO.BADGENUMBER,  USERINFO.NAME,DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME
               FROM USERINFO INNER JOIN CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
               LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENTS ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPTID = USERINFO.DEFAULTDEPTID  
               WHERE DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = '+@DEPTNAME+'
               group by USERINFO.BADGENUMBER,  USERINFO.NAME,DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME
              '
EXEC (@strSql)
```

It is created successfully but when i execute this procedure then it gives error like

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'TBL' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

but when i execute this procedure as a SQL query then it is working fine

It gives error only through procedure.

Comment: You should show how you are calling the procdure, looks like missing quotes for your parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you write a stored procedure just to execute a (wrongly, as you're missing the single quotes in the `WHERE` clause) concatenated SQL string? Try this:

```
USE [Att]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @DEPTNAME varchar(MAX) = '*'
AS BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT  
      USERINFO.BADGENUMBER,        
      USERINFO.NAME,
      DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME
  FROM USERINFO 
      INNER JOIN CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
      LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENTS ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPTID = USERINFO.DEFAULTDEPTID  
  WHERE DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = @DEPTNAME
  GROUP BY 
      USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, USERINFO.NAME, DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME
END
```

Such problems almost always occur when people, instead of using proper SQL try to do stuff using concatenated SQL. This almost always leads to problems.

Comment: ok but can't i store this answer into @strSql varchar(max) variable?

Comment: You can not store the result in a variable easily. It returns a table. If that's what you mean...?

Comment: @deepak while this answer do not use concatenated SQL, it is not necessary to store the query in a variable

Answer (score 1):

Its the issue with the quotation mark for `@DEPTNAME`

try this

```
Set @strSql = 'SELECT DISTINCT  USERINFO.BADGENUMBER,  USERINFO.NAME,DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME
               FROM USERINFO INNER JOIN CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
               LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENTS ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPTID = USERINFO.DEFAULTDEPTID  
               WHERE DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = '''+@DEPTNAME+'''
               group by USERINFO.BADGENUMBER,  USERINFO.NAME,DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed quotes before appending your parameter. Try it like

```
Set @strSql = 'SELECT DISTINCT  USERINFO.BADGENUMBER,  USERINFO.NAME,DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME
           FROM USERINFO INNER JOIN CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
           LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENTS ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPTID = USERINFO.DEFAULTDEPTID  
           WHERE DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = '''+@DEPTNAME+'''
           group by USERINFO.BADGENUMBER,  USERINFO.NAME,DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME
          '
```

Although I agree with @Thorsten that unless its absolutely necessary, do not query using concatenated sql.